# Unity Scene Management and Android - Unable to Load Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new to C#/Unity (be gentle) - I'm trying to create my own script that adds a public variable to the Inspector, doing this allows me to have one script be applicable to multiple GameObjects (or so I thought).

The script is pretty simple.

It works on the PC, but it doesn't work on Android.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class BtnLoadScene : MonoBehaviour {
    public Object SceneObj;
    private string SceneName;

    public void LoadLevel()
    {
        SceneName = SceneObj.name;
        Debug.Log (SceneName);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);
    }
}
```

I'm attaching this script as a component to ALL of my buttons (across the entire app) that drive scene loading.  Again, the value here is that I can then drag my "scene" from assets folder over into the inspector/component (and thus I won't have to explicitly manage "ints" or "strings" - it'll be all done through object references).

See for example:
[image]

Again, <strike>this works on the PC</strike> UPDATE:  As per recommendation in a comment, I tried this in the standalone player and it failed.  This ONLY works in the Unity Editor.  When I build for Android (yes it compiles and I can install the APK) it doesn't work - the first scene loads, the button is responsive to my touch and I see it "depress", but ADB throws:

```
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at BtnLoadScene.LoadLevel () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.028 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at BtnLoadScene.LoadLevel () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1[T0].Invoke (.T0 arg0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger.Execute (EventTriggerType id, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
12-23 15:37:27.036 14816 14847 I Unity   :   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename
```

If I put a hardcoded value (string or scene int) it works fine in Android and PC.  But, for some reason that I can't see, it appears that the Scene object that I've referenced in the Inspector, when I build for Android, isn't capturing the String name and passing it to LoadScene() like I thought.

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?  Is this not possible or a dumb idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to add all the scenes that will be loaded in the game when building it up. If you've done so, try it on pc not from the debugger but from a standalone build. I don't know what might be causing it but you can ask too on the Unity forums.

Comment: @Snak, yeah it was one of the first thing I checked; in the screenshot I provided in the original question I'm showing the scenes that are loaded in the build + the scene object that is referenced in the inspector/component/script.  If I can't solicit a solution here I'll def try the unity forum.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool then. Anyways, I would say the problem is that the SceneObj object is null, and therefore when the code tries to acces it it throws the exception.

Comment: @JustinCarroll There's also a game dev stack exchange site that has what looks like a fairly active [unity tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that `UnityEngine.SceneAsset` can be only used in Editor and it will end up being null in any build.
However, Unity3D needs only a string or index from `BuildSettings` list so it's a no-brainer: just pass scene name in inspector. It would be a constant throughout your development either way and would behave the same if you change scene name as if you would put actual `SceneAsset` object in there (in both cases would fail on rename).

Comment: I was suspecting that too, that's why I told him to do a build for PC and note execute it from the debugger.